# How to include hover in a plotly layout element

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am stuck with the following [plotly example](https://plot.ly/r/shapes/#rectangles) which I would like to exploit:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~uempmed, name = "unemployment")

# add shapes to the layout
p <- layout(p, title = 'Highlighting with Rectangles',
             shapes = list(
               list(type = "rect",
                    fillcolor = "blue", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 0.3,
                    x0 = "1980-01-01", x1 = "1985-01-01", xref = "x",
                    y0 = 4, y1 = 12.5, yref = "y"),
               list(type = "rect",
                 fillcolor = "blue", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 0.2,
                 x0 = "2000-01-01", x1 = "2005-01-01", xref = "x",
                 y0 = 4, y1 = 12.5, yref = "y")))
```

How can I include hover information for those rectangles? Neither of the following works:

```
layout(p, title = 'Highlighting with Rectangles',
            shapes = list(
              list(type = "rect",
                   fillcolor = "blue", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 0.3,
                   x0 = "1980-01-01", x1 = "1985-01-01", xref = "x", 

                   # text - hoverinfo pair
                   text = "hello", hoverinfo = "text",
                   y0 = 4, y1 = 12.5, yref = "y"),
              list(type = "rect",
                   fillcolor = "blue", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 0.2,
                   x0 = "2000-01-01", x1 = "2005-01-01", xref = "x", 

                   # hovertext
                   hovertext = "good bye",
                   y0 = 4, y1 = 12.5, yref = "y")))
```

Is there any way how I can plot rectangles in plotly and apply a hover to them. Unfortunately, at least as I am aware of, there is no `type = "rect"` or anything like that available in R.

Comment: I don't think shapes come with hover by default. A hacky solution would be adding bunch of points with `opacity = 0.0` and assign the desired text to their `hoverinfo`.

Comment: Haha, thank you for your creative suggestion. However, I'd like to highlight some ranges in a time series and a user should see which time they cover. Since some are quite small, I do not think appropriate bubbles can be created automatically :/

Comment: Well, as I said, there's not a conventional way at the moement: https://community.plot.ly/t/shape-hoverinfo-or-restyling/5686, I am thinking of another method, again hacky, which I will post a solution if it worked.

Comment: I haven't used these functions enough to know all the nuances, but I'd recommend using the `add_trace` or `add_polygon` functions instead of add the rectangles in the `layout` function.

Comment: How would you achieve this with `add_polygons`. How would I define the two x-values? And of which trace are you thinking of? It doesnt allow to use something like ´"rect"´. Shortly Ive been hopeful with `add_segment` since you can provide two x and two y values yet it just draws a line instead of a rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding polygons instead of shapes. Look below;

```r
library(plotly)

plot_ly() %>% 
  add_polygons(x=c(as.Date("1980-01-01"), as.Date("1980-01-01"), 
                   as.Date("1985-01-01"), as.Date("1985-01-01")),
               y=c(4, 12.5, 12.5, 4),
               line=list(width=0),
               fillcolor='rgba(255, 212, 96, 0.5)', inherit = FALSE,
               name = 'Hello') %>% 
  add_polygons(x=c(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-01"), 
                   as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2005-01-01")),
               y=c(4, 12.5, 12.5, 4),
               line=list(width=0),
               fillcolor='rgba(255, 212, 96, 0.5)', inherit = FALSE,
               name = 'Bye') %>% 
  add_markers(data = economics, x = ~date, y = ~uempmed, name = "unemployment")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer. Highly appreciated! Since this answers my initial question, I've happily acctepted it as such. Nevertheless, one further query: do you see a potentiall to use variables from a data frame to create multiple of such rectangles? I tried, after rbinding the data, something like `x=c(~V1, ~V2, ~V3, ~V4)` which did not quite work as expected. If you prefer, I can open another question about this issue

Comment: @wusel It's possible, but I need a working example to show how it would implemented. So I think posting another question with a reproducible example would be great. Just tag me here with the link to the new question and I will answer as soon as I can. Cheers.